# pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill() isn't working correctly. Why?

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

So, I use this class in my game:

```
class Magazine(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, shooter):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = shooter.rect.x
        self.rect.y = shooter.rect.y - shooter.image.get_height()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 5
        if self.rect.y <= 0 - self.image.get_height():
            self.kill()
```

After I created this class, I made an item of that class. Then I called its update function:

```
magazine = Magazine(magazineImage, forry)
magazine.update()
```

For some reason I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 106, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 78, in main
    projectileObject.update()
  File "/Users/number1son100/Desktop/Famous Monsters Game/gameobjects.py", line 117, in update
    self.kill()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 174, in kill
    for c in self.__g.keys():
AttributeError: 'Magazine' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so all you need to do is, if you are going to use the functions that come with the sprite class, you first have to insert:

```
super(spritename, self).init()
```

So for this you need to insert:

```
super(Magazine, self).init()
```

into your init function.